# Server Clustering on differen OS : CentOs and Debian

Tags: linux, high-availability, cluster

I have two dedicated servers in two different locations. One at USA (Based on `CentOS`), another at Asia (Based on `Debian`). Need to implement High Availability HTTP Clustering.

The main complexity is different OS. Will `heartbeat` be better or other?

Comment: Why do you need HA? What do you expect from it?

Comment: @Nils, Yes I need High Availability (HA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best clustering solution is a solution at application level, that replicates sessions to all involved servers. If you have that in place you need a DB below that, that replicates the data to both locations.

Having that in place you are ready for load-balancing and have an active-active-cluster with no need for a failover mechanism.

OS should not matter much (could be even Linux and W2K8R2). The only case where you have to think about is the re-join of a node that was down before. The application should not start up until the DB is in sync again.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need or want high-availability clustering, even if you can implement it cheaply using different operating systems thousands of miles apart.

Look at global load balancing, which one or both of your hosting companies may offer. Your URL resolves to a device which then redirects to whichever of your two servers is active (if you regard one as your main site and the other as a disaster recovery site) or to whichever is nearest the end user (as long as both sites are running).

Comment: We can't take hosting companies offer, rather we need to build them. Please refer any service or resource from which we can take help

Comment: Search for global load balancing dns.

Comment: load balancing dns resolves the issue of domain. But i need when a developer uploaded a file to one server then it will be copied to another one. When some changes to one database made, then it will be copied to another one.

Comment: Many databases (e.g., mysql, postgresql, oracle) implement replication technologies that will let you keep two instances of a database in sync. Similarly, there are a number of solutions for file synchronization; the best solution will depend on your requirements.  You might want to open a new question specifically about this issue.

Comment: Modern storage arrays can synchronise files across WANs. It may be cheaper and easier to write a two-line batch file for your developer to upload the file to both systems at once.